# Unable to convert JSON to string in VS 2010

Tags: json

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var empDetails = {
        "ID": 101,
        "Name": ""
    };            
    var result = JSON.stringfy(empDetails);
    $('#div1').html(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, though I'm curious now, but naming the var `result` seems to be the problem. Name it something else.
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43pkvqn5/)

> Update
>   I figured out why it made no sense. You misspelled `stringify`